# How to hide the progress bar?

Tags: r, h2o

It's a simple question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere : how to hide the progress bar in all the h2o functions?

I managed to hide it in Rmarkdown with results = FALSE, but how to hide it in the console?

Answer (score 1):

In the H2O Python API, there is an `h2o.no_progress()` function which disables the progress bar.  You can use `h2o.show_progress()` to re-enable the progress bar.  There is an open [JIRA](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-2586) to add this to the R API (I've been told that it should be available in the next nightly release).